# Using CSS along with GTK+ 3.xx and Glade 3

Tags: css, c, user-interface, gtk

I want to make small GUI based program in C using GTK+ and Glade which would consist of some custom elements, a bit transition effects etc. Can i use Glade along with CSS to create such UI. If so, what is the way to do so ?

Comment: For the record, the "standard" transition effects are done with GtkStack and GtkStackSwitcher. I forget if Glade supports these.